# C++ Struct Lifetime And Scope With Pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, scope

Consider the following example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const int UN_INITIALIZED = -1;


struct Node 
{
  Node *rightNode = nullptr;
  int data = UN_INITIALIZED;
};

struct Test {
    Test()
    {
      root.data = 1;   
    }
    
    void link_nodes()
    {
        Node n;
        cout << "address : " << &n << endl;
        n.data = 5;
        
        root.rightNode = &n;

    } // n is destroyed? n.rightNode shouldn't be defined?
    
    Node root;
    
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.link_nodes();    
    
    // out of scope?
    cout << t.root.rightNode->data << endl; // This return -1
    
    return 0;    
}
```

When running the following example I get a value of `-1` which is the default uninitialized value of `Node::data`. in `link_nodes()` shouldn't `n` be destroyed after the function call ends and calling `->data` should give an error or `seg fault`?

Also when I try creating a different scope in the `main` function the results tend to be correct :

```
int main()
{
    Node root;

    {
        Node n;
        n.data = 55;
        root.rightNode = &n;
    } // n died?
    cout << root.rightNode->data << endl; //gives 55
    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: “Undefined behavior” doesn’t mean “will give an error or sec fault”; rather it means “you messed up, so the code is buggy and whatever happens, happens”

Answer (score 3):

The scope of the variable `n` is the block scope of the member function `link_nodes`.

```
void link_nodes()
{
    Node n;
    cout << "address : " << &n << endl;
    n.data = 5;
    
    root.rightNode = &n;

}
```

After exiting the function the variable `n` having automatic storage duration will not be alive. As a result the pointer `root.rightNode` will be invalid. Dereferencing the pointer results in undefined behavior.

The same problem exists in the second program

```
Node root;

{
    Node n;
    n.data = 55;
    root.rightNode = &n;
} // n died?
cout << root.rightNode->data << endl;
```

Again the variable `n` is not alive after passing the control outside the compound statement where it is defined. So the pointer `root.rightNode` will be invalid.

Comment: this doesn't look to me as an `undefined` behavior. I get an output of `-1` always which is the default value for `data` in the struct.

Comment: @JohnC. If the output is repeated or produces the expected result it does not mean that there is no undefined behavior.:)

Comment: To verify “Always” would require running the program on every conceivable computer and OS and compiler setting, including those not yet created… not an easy claim to validate.

Comment: I edited the question with one more scenario. I would appreciate it if you can explain the differences between both cases. The second scenario produce correct results although the variable is out of scope.

Comment: It’s producing “correct” results only by coincidence; probably the memory that was occupied by the object hasn’t been overwritten by any other data yet at the time you printed it out.  You can’t rely on that behavior though.  (Check out the YouTube video “My little optimizer:  undefined behavior is magic” for examples of why/how relying on undefined behavior can bite you)